# "Your system is running in low-graphics mode'' on an Acer Aspire 5552

Tags: 12.04, ati, updates, laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I own a Acer Aspire 5552 laptop, which has Ubuntu on it. And now i updated it to 12.04 LTS from 11.10.

When i turn the laptop on, it says :

> Your system is running in low-graphics mode, Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

I read about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) already, and it suggested to got to <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F1</kbd> and reinstall my desktop, or install `fglrx`. Well, these things what I read on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125453/your-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-with-an-ati-radeon-3200-graphics-car) site :

Both of them don't work.

And if I don't enter Terminal and just click OK (press Enter, because the mouse cursor isn't there) when it says `you system is running in low-...`, I get options, but i can't choose any of them, can't even click `cancel` or `OK`.
My graphics card is `ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250`.

---

Thanks for the answer:

So, i did everything you said until i had to uninstall the old drivers with the command you gave me. 
I entered it, and it wouldn't finish it.
I googled and tried other things how to manually remove the old drivers on terminal, none of them worked for me. So i can't remove the drivers for some reason.
Oh, and when i enter the code you gave me , it says this :
sh: 0: Can't open /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall

Is there any other way i could get this fixed?
Can i reinstall 12.04 on a USB or something like that? And how would that work?
Thanks :)